# What to pass to Pinterest's iOS 8 app extension?

Tags: ios8, pinterest, ios-app-extension

Is there documentation somewhere?  If I just pass the URL I want to Pin, all the images on the webpage for that URL are shown in the Pinterest share sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass:

- The url that you want to pin (NSURL)
- The image you want the pin to have (UIImage)

Comment: How are you passing both NSURL and UIImage. I'm using a UIActivityItemSource which returns an NSObject that has 2 properties; NSURL and UIImage but Pinterest still presents the user with an image selector from the NSURL provided.